# How to interact with multiple browsers in the same CodedUI test

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to automate a scenario where I login to a site with two users on two different browsers where further interaction will then occur in the same test. It runs up to the point where Chrome has launched the URL and the recorded steps fail giving an error that web page cannot be accessed. The recorded steps do work on Chrome if they were separated out into its testmethod of its own.

```
BrowserWindow window;
window = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://example.com"));               
this.UIMap.ClickOnSignInLink();
this.UIMap.TypeInValidUserCredential();
this.UIMap.ClickOnSignInButton();
this.UIMap.AssertUserIsLoggedIn();


BrowserWindow window2;
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";
window2 = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://example.com"));
this.UIMap.ClickOnSignInLink();
this.UIMap.TypeInValidUserCredential();
this.UIMap.ClickOnSignInButton();
```

Test method FeaturesTest.LiveBidding threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotAvailableException: The web page could not be accessed. If the page is refreshing, please wait until the page refreshes and then perform actions on it.

Comment: Which line *exactly* gives the error? The second URL does not have a `.com` and that would validly provoke a web page does not exist message. As `BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser` is a static property, changing it may affect the behaviour of both `window` and `window2` in your code; the documentation is extremely brief and so is unhelpful on this point.

Comment: Hi sorry that was a typo as I was removing the urls in my test with examples and the actual ones do have .com. I have updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

Only way i managed to do this is by closing the first browser. To do this you can do either of these below. Add this after IE job is finished and you want to switch to Chrome.

```
window.Close();
```

**or** *initialize a new playback*

```
if (Playback.IsInitialized)
{
    Playback.Cleanup();
    Playback.Initialize();
}
```